# Decode a string with both Unicode and Utf-8 codes in Python 2.x

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

Say we have a string:

```
s = '\xe5\xaf\x92\xe5\x81\x87\\u2014\\u2014\xe5\x8e\xa6\xe9\x97\xa8'
```

Somehow two symbols, `'—'`, whose Unicode is `\u2014` was not correctly encoded as `'\xe2\x80\x94'` in UTF-8. Is there an easy way to decode this string? It should be decoded as `寒假——厦门`

Manually using the *replace* function is OK:

```
t = u'\u2014'
s.replace('\u2014', t.encode('utf-8')
print s
```

However, it is not automatic. If we extract the Unicode,

```
index = s.find('\u')
t = s[index : index+6]
```

then `t = '\\u2014'`. How to convert it to UTF-8 code?

Comment: More code required. How are you making a UTF-8 string, with partially converted Unicode literals?  It looks like you've got something fundamentally wrong with your other code that you should fix rather than hack around it

Comment: Some formats can encode strings like this, eg. JSON is a common one these days. If you're trying to parse a JSON string, use a json parser.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing extra slashes in your `replace()`

It should be:

```
s.replace("\\u2014", u'\u2014'.encode("utf-8") )
```

Check my warning in the comments of the question. You should not end up in this situation.